# Review queue number not clearing

Tags: support, bug

The number shown for my review queue does not reset to zero (or change at all) when I clear the queue. Is this just me or is everyone experiencing it?

Comment: [Same thing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236412/187133) since mid-2014. No future. Accept. OBEY.

Comment: @bytebuster Yes I've been noticing it for years, finally thought I'd ask the question. And just found [your question about it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236412/193085). Ah well, I'll live with it.

Comment: I don't really understand how that counter works. I started with my queue now, when it was showing "12" in the top-bar. Closing or migrating questions decremented the counter, whereas leaving them open or skipping them let the counter remain unchanged. Finally, there was just one question left in my queue, and the counter showed "5". I closed the question, and the counter disappeared from the top-bar. And now, all the counters in my review queue show 0. All I can conclude is that the counter works in mysterious ways.

Comment: @prash I think the answer to the question linked in my above comment clarifies. The review queue number is the items open for review on the site, not just for you. If you have worked through your review queue and 'skipped' some (or there are ones you're not eligible to view) then you won't see them them in your queue but the number will still show.

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut Sure, but that does not explain why my count went from 5 to 0 after reviewing the last question in my queue.

Comment: It's very broken. I have only one site where I have access to the mod tools, but the number usually shows stuff when there's nothing for me to do, except for now when even though there was an edit to review, it wasn't showing! I've found that it's useful for suggested edits on sites where you don't have mod tools, but useless on sites where you have the mod tools.